# Create a sub menu from a MySql table with PHP

Tags: php

I've the following data structure:

```
|--------|----------|-----------|------------|-----------------|
| NAV_Id | NAV_Name | NAV_Order | NAV_Parent | NAV_ParentOrder |
|--------|----------|-----------|------------|-----------------|
|      1 |     Home |         1 |         no |               0 |
|      2 |   Fruits |         2 |        yes |               0 |
|      3 |   Apples |         2 |         no |               1 |
|      4 |    Pears |         2 |         no |               2 |
|--------|----------|-----------|------------|-----------------|
```

- `NAV_Order` is the nav position in my menu.
- `NAV_Parent` is if the item has a submenu.
- `NAV_ParentOrder` is the position order of the item in the sub menu.

My desired output is the following:

```
<ol class="dd-list">
    <li class="dd-item" data-id="1">
        <div class="dd-handle">Home</div>
    </li>
    <li class="dd-item" data-id="2">
        <div class="dd-handle">Fruits</div>
        <ol class="dd-list">
            <li class="dd-item" data-id="3"><div class="dd-handle">Apples</div></li>
            <li class="dd-item" data-id="4"><div class="dd-handle">Pears</div></li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

How, from my database structure I can reflect this output please ?

Here what I try actually:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM ___Navigation');
$query->execute();

while ($fetch = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if(NAV_Parent == 0) {
        echo '<li class="dd-item" data-id="'.$fetch[NAV_Id].'"><div class="dd-handle">'.$fetch[NAV_Name].'</div></li>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<li class="dd-item" data-id="'.$fetch[NAV_Id].'"><div class="dd-handle">'.$fetch[NAV_Name].'</div></li>';
        foreach($fetch[NAV_ParentOrder]) {
            echo '<li class="dd-item" data-id="'.$fetch[NAV_Id].'"><div class="dd-handle">'.$fetch[NAV_Name].'</div></li>';
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm totally lost...

Answer (score 0):

how about :

```
$query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM ___Navigation WHERE NAV_ParentOrder=0 ORDER BY NAV_Order');
$query->execute();
while ($fetch = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    //your parent menu
    print '<li class="dd-item" data-id="' . $fetch[NAV_Id] . '"><div class="dd-handle">' . $fetch[NAV_Name] . '</div></li>';
    $query_child = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM ___Navigation WHERE NAV_ParentOrder !=0 AND NAV_ParentOrder=' . $fetch[NAV_Id] . 'ORDER BY NAV_Order');
    $query_child->execute();
//child menu
    while ($fetch_child = $query_child->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        print '<ol class="dd-list">';
        print '<li class="dd-item" data-id="' . $fetch_child[NAV_Id] . '"><div class="dd-handle">' . $fetch_child[NAV_Name] . '</div></li>';
    }
}
```